# How to record events for opening PDF file in web application in load runner - vugen?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

**Dear Friends,**

Greetings.

I have a web application, where I would be selecting some options and generate pdf report. Once clicked **"generate report"** button, a pdf file would get downloaded. I have written a code to capture pdf download time and pdf downloaded size. But the intention is to capture the time to open the downloaded pdf file.

To be simple, I just want to enable load runner or fiddler to capture events for **opening pdf file.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks for your understanding.

**With Regards,**

**Yasir.**

Comment: What exactly is the time for opening the pdf file? For example, if you are opening with Acobat Reader what events do you expect to capture? How is that even related to performance testing? Are you testing the performance of the host machine?

Comment: Thanks Buzzy for your response. Actually, My client wanted to trace out the pdf report opening time during load test. Right now it is not taking more than a sec to open pdf file via acrobat reader.. but let say how about 1000 users accessing the application and concurrently opening pdf? This is what our intention is. If load runner captures the events for opening pdf file, then we would be able to do load test on that exact requests. But Load runner is not capturing those events. Thats the issue. Even fiddler is not recording the pdf opening events. How to handle this situation?

Comment: What you are describing is NOT a load test. It will not test anything at all. A load test, tests the server or the client experience against the server and not operation which is done entirely on the client.

Comment: GUI Virtual User